# How to set Facebook user profile picture with a link?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

My app uploads a picture to the user's album through graph API (/me/photos) and then grabs that picture, makes it user profile picture by sending the user to

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=[PID]&makeprofile=1

It worked well, the user would be presented with the page that he could crop and save right away. However, just 2 days ago, the page was changed. The user will, instead, be presented with the picture in theatre mode (popup on black screen) and has to click a non-obvious link "Make Profile Picture" to crop and save.

The question is, it is the url that was just changed, or it is a new policy of Facebook. If it is a policy, I would like to have the link that this matter was announced

See the picture here, https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0vWR6nY09_wRzhwU3VadG81TGM. It used to be like on the left but now it is the one on the right

Comment: For changes regarding the API, you can expect Facebook to announce those upfront. But you are not using an API feature here. This is just a minor UI change, and those do not get announced.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. I have asked Facebook support and they said that URL is not meant for 3rd party in the beginning

Comment: @ChatpongSuteesuksataporn Did you find a solution to this problem? A different link or way to achieve that feat?

Comment: Yes, does anyone know how to do this?